# Store null values in database while trying to save data using spring mvc angular js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

angular js code

```
 <body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="UserController as userBean">
<form method="post" action="register" name="myForm">
<div class="form-group col-lg-7" >
  <label for="username" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="userBean.username" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Firstname"/><br>
   <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="userBean.phone" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter phone no."/><br>
  <label for="email" class="control-label">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="userBean.email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter email"/><br>
  <label for="address" class="control-label">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="userBean.address" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter address"/><br>
  <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" data-ng-model="userBean.password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter password"/><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-7">
   <button type="submit" data-ng-click="insertData()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("UserController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, httpPostService) {
 var self=this;

$scope.insertData = function()
{
    alert($scope.userBean.username, $scope.userBean.phone, $scope.userBean.email);
     $http({
         method: "POST",
         url: "register",
         data:{
         username: $scope.userBean.username,
         phone: $scope.userBean.phone,
         email: $scope.userBean.email,
         address: $scope.userBean.address,
         password: $scope.userBean.password}
        }).then(function(response){
         console.log(response.status);
         console.log("in success");

     }, function(response){
         console.log(response.status);
         console.log("in fail");     
     });
};
}]);
</script>
```

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView doRegister(@ModelAttribute @RequestBody UserBean userBean, BindingResult result)
    {

        if(!result.hasFieldErrors())
        {
            if(retrieveService.insert(userBean) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("done");

            }

        }   
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/welcome");

    }
}
```

I think a controller problem. userBean has null values to pass it to a controller. so kindly anyone helps me
It error also came

> HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not
>   supported by this method on the target resource.

Answer (score 0):

Set content type JSON in your request headers like below.

```
$http({
         method: "POST",
         url: "register",
         data:{
         username: $scope.userBean.username,
         phone: $scope.userBean.phone,
         email: $scope.userBean.email,
         address: $scope.userBean.address,
         password: $scope.userBean.password},
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
```

Comment: In console shows error like this Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()

Answer (score 0):

Use @JsonIgnore on the field which can have null values.